# PhpStorm File Watcher change output

Tags: compilation, phpstorm

I'm trying to output the compiled CSS to a different directory.

***/project/scss/*** to ***/project/css/***

I've tried this, but get the error below:

[image]
Error: `error No such file or directory - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/public/css/style.scss`

What are the *Arguments* and *Output paths to refresh* exactly for?

Comment: What is the exact command that IDE executes? It should show the actual paths that IDE inserted instead of marcos/placeholders.

Comment: @LazyOne `error No such file or directory - /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/public/css/style.scss`

Comment: 1) Does `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/public/css/` folder exist and is accessible for that tool? 2) Try `..` instead of `$FileParentDir$`. I'm using node-sass .. and there command line parameters are different .. and I have never seen such issue myself (plus I'm on Windows).

Comment: *"What are the Arguments and Output paths to refresh exactly for?"* Well... "Arguments" field must be self-explanatory. The "Output paths to refresh" tells IDE what files to check after compilation is done (file watcher has run the program and it finished, successfully or not) -- this is so it is aware of the changes made to the files (as such changes are happening outside of IDE .. and refreshing whole project may not be good idea in some environments (e.g. huge project or slow disk etc.)) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/new-watcher-dialog.html#d193609e118

Comment: Here is potentially similar ticket .. but no response from the author: did he managed to fix it and what the issue was: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44256620/783119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working now with the following settings:
[image]

The only difference now is the **Output paths to refresh** field. It's the default now.

Answer (score 0):

**$FileParentDir$** contains the path of the parent SCSS file. So in our case it will be **/project/scss**. In order to make it work like you need, it is necessary to use **$ProjectFileDir$** variable or (if you insist to use $FileParentDir$) **$FileParentDir$/../** so it would go to an upper level directory.
If you will open any file in Editor and then go to Preferences | Tools | File Watchers > edit your file watcher settings > press Insert Macro button, you will see the list of all the variables with previews for currently opened file so you can see the values and build the arguments accordingly.
Note that *Output paths to refresh* also should be modified according to the Arguments path.